# Jquery problems with Bootstrap 3 and KendoUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm experiencing a little issue with these two frameworks and their respective use of jquery.
As my template in Visual studio 2013 includes Bootstrap 3 it also comes bundled with `jquery-2.0.3.js` This is all fine until I need to use KendoUI's `jquery.js` (v1.9.1) as well.

They're both included in the `_Layout.cshtml` like this:

```
...
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Kendo/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>'
</head>
<body>
...
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

The error causes my Kendo grid not to render templates and the console window in chrome shows the following error:
[image]

I've had this working before, when on Bootstrap 2.3.2, but the entire project is updated. What effect would loosing the `jquery-2.0.3.js` have on my application? Removing this resolves the problem, but I don't know what parts of the Bootstrap framework will be affected by this. Finally, I know I'm not supposed to include the jquery-files twice (Bootstrap + KendoUI), but how should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Bootstrap's "Getting Started"](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included) and the linked [bower file](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.0.2/bower.json), which declares the jQuery dependency as `"jquery": ">= 1.9.0"`, I'd say you can safely use Bootstrap 3 with jquery-1.9.1.

Comment: Thank you! Guess the Bootstrap team is a bit further ahead when it comes to jquery-versions :) Hopefully they'll announce an updated version in their Q3-release tomorrow :)